# AS3 shooting in multiple directions

Tags: actionscript-3, trigonometry

i am try trying to make space shooter game in which ship is able to rotate and shoot in all directions, now, i do know basics of trigonometry, but i stuck at this point and my brain seems to be frozen so i seek your help.

I have **Ship.as** and **Turret.as** , every ship contains some number of turrets, and this is loop that is responsible to create bullet for each turret on players input and its located in Ship.as.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < turrets.length; i++)
            {
                var _pcos:Number = Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI);
                var _psin:Number = Math.sin(angle / 180 * Math.PI);
                var bulletX:Number = center.x + turrets[i].distance * _pcos;
                var bulletY:Number = center.y + turrets[i].distance * _psin;

                var bullet:BulletBase = new bulletClass(bulletX, bulletY, angle);
                layerBullets.add(bullet);

                bullets.push(bullet);
            }
```

variable **center** is point positioned in exact center of ships sprite, **angle** is ships rotation towards mouse, **turret.distance** is distance from **center** to **turret**

This is whats happening in Turret.as

```
public class Turret extends Point
{
    private var ship:Ship;
    public var distance:Number;
    public var angle:Number;
    /**
     *
     * @param   x position with angle 0
     * @param   y position with angle 0
     * @param   distance distance from center of ship to turret
     */
    public function Turret(x:Number = 0, y:Number = 0, ship:Ship = null)
    {
        super(x, y);
        this.ship = ship;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        var dx:Number = ship.center.x - x;
        var dy:Number = ship.center.y - y;

        angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

        distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
```

Now, what is happening with this code is that bullets seems like they are fired from same direction, only one bullet is behind.

I am not math expert and if anyone knows the answer i would really appreciate it.

Comment: ITS fixed, i needed to add angle between turret and center to ship angle when calculating _pcos and _psin :D

Comment: Please post this as an answer (yes, on your own question), so you can mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var _pcos:Number = Math.cos((turret.angle + angle) / 180 * Math.PI);
var _psin:Number = Math.sin((turret.angle + angle) / 180 * Math.PI);
```

angle is angle of ship